# Recuperate information of cookie with jquery.cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-plugins, jquery-cookie

I created a cookie "__utmz" with the following information on link in other page:

```
174779773.1409222545.1.1.utmcsr=GOOGLE|utmccn=MARCA-EXACT-S|utmcmd=SEM_CPC
```

Before recovering the "utmcrs", "utmccm" etc.With php language and working properly:

```
 $pattern = "/^(\d*\.*)*(utm.*)$/";
 preg_match($pattern, $_COOKIE['__utmz'], $matches);
 $utm_str_vars = explode("|",$matches[2]);
 $utm_vars = array();
 foreach ($utm_str_vars AS $utm_var) {
   list ($utm_key, $utm_val) = explode ("=", $utm_var);
   $utm_vars[$utm_key] = str_replace("'", "\'", $utm_val);
 }
```

Now I need to do it with Jquery.cookie, but I get done with the information provided me documentation jquery, can not get the string values ​​recover.
I inserted the code:

```
value=$.cookie("__utmz");
alert(value);//display the information
```

Now I need help to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: How are you creating the cookie??

Comment: the cookie is created when a user accesses a landing page that redirects to the page you pick values​​. The cookie is created correctly because with php functions can work with their values ​​as I commented in the previous text.